# Unable to signin to github via vscode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I've been trying to login to github via vscode so I can use the built in features. Everytime I've tried to login I always get the same error  `Sign in failed: FetchError: request to https://vscode-auth.github.com/token?code=xxxxx&state=xxxx failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate.`
I've tried to do `"http.proxyStrictSSL": false` in my vscode settings but that does not work either. I've tried it on my raspberry pi and it does work. Could someone please help me? The machine I am using is macOS version 10.13.6 and I am using the latest version of vscode.